# Dependency on 3rd party at runtime?

Tags: java, applet, dependencies, javafx

We have created an applet with javafx and it seems that in order to load the applet several jar, jnlp and js files are required to be downloaded from `dl.javafx.com`. I tried to work out which files were needed so I could host them on our own server but after spending an hour or so on it I got tired of reading code and gave up. Doesn't it seem bizarre that to use javafx the client has a dependency on the javafx server? There was an instance a few months ago where their server was down which is completely unacceptable. I feel like scrapping it and starting again in something else but I can't throw a years work away.

What are everyone else's views? Have you experienced/solved this? Any suggestions where I should go from here will be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has come up a few times and it is one of the main gripes people have with JavaFX.  There is a dependency on the runtime, however I believe it is technically possible to distribute an app "offline" (though I've never tried it).  See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/deployment_toolkit/index.html) and [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5367483).

I am not sure whether or not it is a breach of the license to distribute offline.

I have sympathy with your frustration, but I would argue that it would not be worth scrapping a year's work.  I imagine the uptime of the Oracle servers would be no worse than any outage that could be expected of any web application.